# onsubmit not called when form submitted

Tags: javascript, html

```
 <form class="form-horizontal custom-form" id="signupform" method='post' action='/controller' onsubmit='return signupvalidation()'>

 <button class="btn btn-default submit-button" type="button" >Sign Up</button>

 </form>
```

in my js file

```
  function signupvalidation(){

    aletr("some text");
    return true;
}
```

I have put a link of js file in my jsp file. but still function is not called. Please help!

Comment: make button type="submit" and it will work

Answer (score 2):

Button type should be submit

```
 <button class="btn btn-default submit-button" type="submit" >Sign Up</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake I should set the type of my button as submit.
like this.

```
<input type="submit" > </input>
```